# subprocess failed when used in supervisor

Tags: python, subprocess, celery, supervisord

I have a celery task which does:

```
subprocess.check_call([script.sh, 'clean'], cwd=module_folder, stdout=fd_log_out, stderr=fd_log_err)
```

When I run the worker from the command line all is OK.

When the celery workers are started from supervisor, I get this in my logs:

```
[2016-05-09 10:31:30,129: ERROR/MainProcess] Task project_server.executions.tasks.execution_run[04e6295b-2aa4-4384-9218-fccb111a20df] raised unexpected: TypeError('expect bytes or str, not NoneType',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/benjamin/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/benjamin/Project/projectserver/project_server/executions/tasks.py", line 88, in execution_run
    fd_log_err=fd_log_err)
  File "/home/benjamin/Project/projectcommon/project_common/generator/__init__.py", line 807, in create_application
    fd_log_out, fd_log_err)
  File "/home/benjamin/Project/projectcommon/project_common/models/extensions.py", line 550, in build_scala_module
    subprocess.check_call([script.sh, 'clean'], cwd=module_folder, stdout=fd_log_out, stderr=fd_log_err)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 556, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1381, in _execute_child
    executable = os.fsencode(executable)
  File "/home/benjamin/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 770, in fsencode
    raise TypeError("expect bytes or str, not %s" % type(filename).__name__)
TypeError: expect bytes or str, not NoneType
```

Why does it fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i got it: script.sh was not in the $PATH given by supervisor

Answer (score 0):

To fix the same error when run python script via systemd include WorkingDirectory to the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/script
User=user
Group=group

Type=idle
ExecStart=/path/to/python runner.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you write like this (full path to script without WorkingDirectory)

```
ExecStart=/path/to/python /path/to/script/runner.py
```

you will have error.